# How can a GitHub profile contributions graph that is screwed up because of an incorrect e-mail address be fixed?

Tags: git, github

I checked my GitHub profile contributions graph recently and discovered that none of my contributions are shown on it since a few months ago. According to this [help article](https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile/), this may have arisen because an incorrect GitHub e-mail address was set for me in a library sourced by `.bashrc`.

So, something like the following was set

```
git config --global user.email "othersupercooladdress@sern.ch"
```

when it should have been something else:

```
git config --global user.email "supercooladdress@sern.ch"
```

All of the commit records are fine and I'd like the contributions graph to be an accurate reflection of my contributions. How can this be fixed? Could the other e-mail address (it is a valid one for me too) be set as valid too somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes :-)
Just add them to your GitHub profile at https://github.com/settings/emails

Comment: Excellent, that worked! Thanks muchly for your help. Now I can see all my statistics.

Answer (score 1):

As you know the email config is just a string used for the commit SHA-1 calculation.

You can set the email as global config value or pass it to your commit with the `git commit -c user.email ...`

In GitHub the case is much more simple. You have to define the emails of your contributors if they did not do so. To do it is very simple.

Tell them to login to their account and set the email. From this point on GitHub will "fix" and track the commits by their names.

Another option which is less recommended is to use `git filter-branch` to "fix" all the required email addresses. The result of this action is a rebase and this is why it is not the recommended option.

---

#### ***`Last note`***

Your GitHub contributors can set their email to be a private email so it will not appear in the commit message.

[image]